# How can I insert number in database as Giving error out of range?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to insert the mobile number. But it is not taking the number. What can I do??

```
mysql>create table mob(MobNo int(30));
mysql>insert into mob1 values(9876543211);
```

Gives error:

```
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'MobNo' at row 1
```

Thank you..

Comment: Save it as varchar, why are int??

Comment: @AlonEital If someone enters a character other than a number then It will give an error.

Comment: What you think if we think for security purposes can we take String or Integer As I am a beginner I have no more idea.?

Comment: You need to validate the input and remove all none numeric characters, or display an error to the user about invalid input. You should not use the field type in the database as a solution

Comment: @AlonEitan I didn't get how to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, an [unsinged `int`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) can hold values up to `4294967295`; yours is approximately twice bigger, so I can't fit.

Use `bigint`:

```
create table mob(MobNo bigint);
```

You might be under the imperssion that `30` in `int(30)` gives you a 30 digit precision. That's actually not the case; the number within the parentheses is the *display width*: if relates to the representation of the number, and does not change the range of values it may store. This is somehow tricky, and this syntax is now [planned for deprecation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html):

> As of MySQL 8.0.17, the display width attribute is deprecated for integer data types; you should expect support for it to be removed in a future version of MySQL.

Comment: bigint won't allow 30 digits; use `decimal(30,0)`.  Likely they want unsigned too